# Retrying a Scrapy Request even when receiving a 200 status code

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

There is a website I'm scraping that will sometimes return a 200, but not have any text in response.body (raises an AttributeError when I try to parse it with Selector).

Is there a simple way to check to make sure the body includes text, and if not, retry the request until it does? Here is some pseudocode to outline what I'm trying to do.

```
def check_response(response):
    if response.body != '':
        return response
    else:
        return Request(copy_of_response.request,
                       callback=check_response)
```

Basically, is there a way I can repeat a request with the exact same properties (method, url, payload, cookies, etc.)?

Answer (score 12):

Follow the [`EAFP` principle](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.

Handle an exception and yield a `Request` to the current url with [`dont_filter=True`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request):

> dont_filter (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be
>   filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an
>   identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use
>   it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

```
def parse(response):
    try:
        # parsing logic here
    except AttributeError:
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

---

You can also [*make a copy*](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.copy) of the current request (not tested):

```
new_request = response.request.copy()
new_request.dont_filter = True
yield new_request
```

Or, make a new request using [`replace()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.replace):

```
new_request = response.request.replace(dont_filter=True)
yield new_request
```

Comment: This would work if all my requests were GET requests, is there an elegant way to handle different methods? Otherwise I guess could do something like: if response.request.method == 'POST' -> yield FormRequest()

Comment: @chr1sbest the idea stays the same `FormRequest` is a subclass of a `Request` and there `dont_filter` there also - just make sure you are specifying the current callback in the `callback` argument.

Answer (score 10):

How about calling actual `_rety()` method from retry middleware, so it acts as a normal retry with all it's logic that takes settings into account?

In settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'scraper.middlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 550,
}
```

Then your retry middleware could be like:

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware \
    as BaseRetryMiddleware


class RetryMiddleware(BaseRetryMiddleware):


    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # inject retry method so request could be retried by some conditions
        # from spider itself even on 200 responses
        if not hasattr(spider, '_retry'):
            spider._retry = self._retry
        return super(RetryMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response, spider)
```

And then in your success response callback you can call for ex.:

```
yield self._retry(response.request, ValueError, self)
```

Comment: Nowadays it looks like there is API for that, so it's better to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/73659837/1300386

Answer (score 3):

From Scrapy 2.5.0 there is a new method `get_retry_request()`.

It's pretty easy, the example from the Scrapy docs:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if not response.text:
        new_request_or_none = get_retry_request(
            response.request,
            spider=self,
            reason='empty',
        )
        return new_request_or_none
```

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.get_retry_request

Answer (score 0):

in your existing code, you can simply allow duplicate filter=True

```
def check_response(response):
if response.body != '':
    return response
else:
    return Request(copy_of_response.request,
                   callback=check_response, dont_filter=True)
```