# How to allow the same request n times at most?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I request a server sometimes it replies a webpage that isn't the one that is expected even when the response status is 200.I know I can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640102/retrying-a-scrapy-request-even-when-receiving-a-200-status-code) to request the same url multiple times :

```
def parse(response):
    try:
        # parsing logic here
    except AttributeError:
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

But how would one do to limit the amount of times, let's say 10 times, that the same url can be requested to avoid infinite loops when the webpage really is what it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add a parameter to call `parse` with the parameter of the number of attempts already done. In case this is higher than a certain threshold (here 10), you do not `yield` a new `Request`. So:

```
from functools import partial

def parse(response,ntimes=0):
    try:
        # parsing logic here
        pass
    except AttributeError:
        if ntimes < 10:
            yield Request(response.url, callback=partial(self.parse,ntimes=ntimes+1), dont_filter=True)
```

So here instead of using `parse` as the callback you wrap a `partial(..)` around it setting `ntimes` to the previous `ntimes+1` (so you *increment* the "virtual" counter so to speak). When `ntimes` is 10 or higher, you no longer add the a request to the queue.

You set `ntimes=0` by default to be `0` such that you can still add a reference to `parse` without specifying the amount of times it has been called (in that case `parse` "assumes" the url is not yet been called).

Comment: thanks, using the same logic one could use `meta` too I guess.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs: indeed. But it would require that you first check whether such meta is attached to the `response` while this answer provides a way that is transparent about that. But indeed, as long as you can attach information about the number of calls done to your response somehow, it will work.